# How to get/set Azure AD B2C User MFA details via Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, multi-factor-authentication

**Using the Microsoft Graph API v 1.0, how can I retrieve the user's MFA details?**

For example, if I have an email based sign-in/sign-up policy with phone/SMS MFA, how can I see the phone number entered by the user? (and also set update it)

I know if I select 'identities' in the GET /users method I can see the email they've signed up with, but not the phone number they set for MFA.  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Of course I'm looking for all the mfa settings: mfa phone number, mfa email address, is mfa set, etc.

Hopefully there is some kind of extension attribute that contains this that I can select, and set on creation, but I cannot find documentation on this.

[UPDATE]
In the Azure portal, I can see the entered data if I go to user > profile > authentication methods. So I tried accessing the authentication relationships on the user. but it didn't provide any details (all empty arrays) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/authentication?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a write-up [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/proofing-up-users-programmatically-on-azure-ad-b2c-using-either-email-or-phone-71a71f579235).

e.g:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/objectID/authentication/methods
```

Comment: Ah, so only beta, and cannot be included in the same call with the rest of the user data I guess.